# How do i do with java to fetch two to two numbers in a string and convert them

Tags: java, string

I have a problem with convention of a `String` to dec of hex.  I have to take the `String` in input and convert the numers two to two for example:
string in input = FFCF6781.
I have to take FF and convert, after take CF and convert and so on.

My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/*
 * Sample java source code convert hexadecimal to decimal
 */

public class HexToDecimal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hexadecimal Input:");
        // read the hexadecimal input from the console
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputHex = s.nextLine();
        String str = inputHex;


            try{
                for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
                    inputHex = str.substring (i,i+2);

        // actual conversion of hex to decimal
            Integer outputDecimal = Integer.parseInt(inputHex, 16);
            System.out.println("Decimal Equivalent : "+outputDecimal);

        }
           catch(NumberFormatException ne){
            // Printing a warning message if the input is not a valid hex number
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");

        }

       finally{
       s.close();   


    }

    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem? (Note: you should be as specific as you can, just "it doesn't work" won't do.)

Comment: One thing that is quite obvious: have a look at your for-loop and check which statements are inside the loop. Then think about what `inputHex` will be after the loop finished.

Comment: Your for loop is braced incorrectly. The only line looped is inputHex = str.substring(). You need braces around up to after the System.out.println.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things.

First of all, if you want to print every hexadecimal number, you need to expand your for loop.

Plus, you need to add 2 to `i` every iteration.

In case the input length is not dividable by 2, catch the OutOfBoundsException.

This code works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Hexadecimal Input:");
    // read the hexadecimal input from the console
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputHex = s.nextLine();
    String str = inputHex;

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i+=2) {
            inputHex = str.substring(i, i + 2);

            // actual conversion of hex to decimal
            Integer outputDecimal = Integer.parseInt(inputHex, 16);
            System.out.println("Decimal Equivalent : " + outputDecimal);
        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        // Printing a warning message if the input is not a valid hex number
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");

    }

    finally {
        s.close();

    }

}
```